# Proof of the formula for a $2 \times 2$ matrix exponential with trace $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation, trace, matrix-exponential

Can someone please offer a proof that the matrix exponential of a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ with trace $0$ is the following??
\begin{equation}
\exp(A)=\cos(\sqrt{\det A})I+\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\det A})}{\sqrt{\det A}}A
\end{equation}

Comment: Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: That doesn't really help.

Comment: It does help those who are trying to answer your question as well as the search engine for this site (that cannot parse images).

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to add those codes in for the context to be searchable? I see people use $ \times $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $A$ is $2\times2$ and $\text{Tr}A = 0$, $A$ can be written as
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
a & c\\
b & -a
\end{matrix}\right),$$ and $A^2 = -\vert A \vert\cdot I_2$, where $\vert A\vert = \det(A)$, and $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. 
\begin{align*} & \exp(A) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{n!} \\
= &\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{A^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{A^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \\
= & \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\vert A\vert^kI_2}{(2k)!} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\vert A\vert^kA}{(2k+1)!} \\
= & \cos\left(\sqrt{\det(A)}\right)I_2 + \frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{\det(A)}\right)}{\sqrt{\det(A)}}A.
\end{align*}

Comment: Good job! ${}{}$

Comment: Wait but det(A) times the identity matrix is negative A squared isn't it?

Comment: @user7697538 Thank yo so much for pointing it out.  I corrected my post.

Comment: No no, thank you so much for this answer, it helped so much in understanding this!